# protractor launches chrome data:. url and takes almost 10 minutes to navigate to application URL

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver

My protractor scripts were running fine on Chrome V62 & chromeDriver 2.35. My browser got updated to v64 and from then on, i m experiencing the wierd behaviour where my browser opens with "data.;" & then hangs for 10 min and then proceeds with execution.

I updated my chromeBrowser to 2.36 & also selenium server to 3.12.0. on running "webdriver-manager update" it says: all are uptodate. Not sure what is causing the issue.

Versions:
Node: 8.8.1
protractor : 5.3
Chrome: 64
ChromeDriver:2.36
seleniumserver: 3.12.0

& directConnect:true.

All of the versions is samefrom the begining, except for chromeDriver & chrome. Can canyone tell me what went wrong please.

Comment: could you try on the last version of Chrome - v 67?

Comment: I cannot as i do not have admin permission to update browser

Comment: So, let's make a new communication path with someone who has :)

Comment: Its working fine on updating chrome-Driver to 2.36